# Single instance AWS HTTPS with StartSSL on mobile does not work

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, nginx, amazon-ec2, https

I have deployed and run an **https** app on a single instance (AWS EC2) with nginx. I use **StarSSL** certificates.

Everything works fine on desktop but on **mobile** I got this error:
`NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`

After research, I tried this :

`cat my.personal.cert ca.crt sub.class1.server.sha1.ca.crt > site.ssl.cert`

I found the 2 last certificates on the startssl [website](https://www.startssl.com/root)

site.ssl.cert is located on ec2 at `/etc/pki/tls/certs/site.ssl.cert`

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: try this https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html can you share the report with us ? is there anything wrong ?

Comment: I got an Chain issues : Incomplete

Comment: `cat my.personal.cert sub.class1.server.sha1.ca.crt ca.crt > site.ssl.cert` ... the order matters.

Comment: It doesn't work with your order too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check your `site.ssl.cert` file and make sure the certificate separators look like:

```
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
```

And **not** like this:

```
-----END CERTIFICATE----------BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
```

The last time I used `cat` on intermediate certificates it didn't work as expected. A newline was missing.

Comment: I don't have this. but the sub.class1.server.sha1. and ca.crt ca.crt is not a string. It's maybe that?

Answer (score 0):

A certificat was missing. Consequently, the chain wasn't respected.